# Euro symbol in Jupyter Latex

Tags: node.js, latex, jupyter, euro

I am new to Jupyter, I am using it with Node Kernel. 
My problem is I can't get the "euro" symbol in LaTeX. 
When I type `$ 123 \euro $` in a Markdown cell I get `123 \euro`.

Do you observe the same behavior ? Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance,

Nicola

Comment: Writing `$123€$` works for me, but it is probably better `$123$ €`

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX support in the live notebook is limited to what [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) support. MathJax goal indicate:

> high-quality display of mathematics notation in all browsers

And in practice, this mean trying to have a narrow scope which is way less than full latex. `\euro` is probably outside of their scope, so won't render in live notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Matt comment i found a partial solution in [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mathjax-users/Zx0sVa0fBvg).

You can define all currency symbols you want in Jupyter placing something linke this in a MarkDown cell:

```
$ \def\euro{\unicode{x20AC}} $
$ \def\yen{\unicode{x00A5}}  $
$ \def\pound{\unicode{x00A3}} $
$ \def\dollar{\unicode{x024}} $
```

With the above definitions you can now use `\euro`, `\yen`, `\pound` and `\dollar`. I defined dollar in this way for consistency only since it can be written as `\$`. I found the unicode for each symbol in Wikipedia.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste the symbol from somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe the wording is not precise and it may not work in all circumstances, but for me rather than calling \euro{} or trying some custom unicode definition, the easiest way was indeed to just google euro, copy the symbol and write "my label with €" to print the correct symbol...